# ANTLR 4 java.g4 -> weird grammar rule

Tags: grammar, lexer, antlr4

here is one of the rule I have seen in java.g4:

DecimalLiteral : ('0' | '1'..'9' '0'..'9'*) IntegerTypeSuffix? ;

Why not writing it this way:

DecimalLiteral : ('0'..'9'+) IntegerTypeSuffix? ;

Is there anything I'm missing ? 
Thank you for your feedback

Regards
Philippe Frankson

Answer (score 4):

The intent is to have `0` be a `DecimalLiteral`, but all other integers starting with `0` be an `OctalLiteral`.

I would prefer to use a pair of rules like this:

```
OctalLiteral : '0'+ [1-7] [0-7]* IntegerTypeSuffix?;
DecimalLiteral : [0-9]+ IntegerTypeSuffix?;
```

And then defer validation of invalid octal integers (which this pair of rules would still accept as a `DecimalLiteral`) to a later step in the parsing process.

Comment: note: on a grammatical level this is significant, but in sane cases it shouldn't matter if 0 is parsed as octal 0 or decimal 0: they will most likely end up having the same in-memory representation. `DecimalLiteral : '1'..'9' '0'..'9'* IntegerTypeSuffix? ;` should probably suffice